# I am trying to consume a java web service from .NET. i am not getting proper output

Tags: java, java-client

code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        System.out.println("Enter the BookName:");
        String bookName = br.readLine();
        System.out.println("Book Id is: " +bookInfo(bookName).getBookAvail().get(0).getBookID().toString());
        System.out.println("Book Name is: " +bookInfo(bookName).getBookAvail().get(0).getBookName().toString());
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
     try {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        System.out.println("Enter the StudentID:");
        String studentID = br.readLine();
        System.out.println("Student Information is: " +studentInfo(studentID));
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}

private static ArrayOfBookAvail bookInfo(java.lang.String bookName) {
    org.tempuri.BookService service = new org.tempuri.BookService();
    org.tempuri.IBookService port = service.getBasicHttpBindingIBookService();
    return port.bookInfo(bookName);
}

private static ArrayOfStudInfo studentInfo(java.lang.String studentID) {
    org.tempuri.BookService service = new org.tempuri.BookService();
    org.tempuri.IBookService port = service.getBasicHttpBindingIBookService();
    return port.studentInfo(studentID);
}

}
```

and the output which i am getting is:

```
Enter the BookName:
Core Servlets and JavaServer Pages, Volume 2:Advanced Technologies
Book Id is: javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement@196da649
Enter the StudentID:
    13MCAL058
Student Information is: org.datacontract.schemas._2004._07.lms.ArrayOfStudInfo@2b08bc5a
```

please help to get the proper output.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: What output do you expect? Can you simplify the code? It is a lot to read through

Comment: What error?  That looks like a typical `toString` on a class that hasn't overrode it.

Comment: By the way, I don't see any .NET code here.

Answer (score 0):

```
Book Id is: javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement@196da649
```

Looks like `bookInfo(bookName).getBookAvail().get(0).getBookID()` returns a [`JAXBElement`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/JAXBElement.html). You can just call [`getValue()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/JAXBElement.html#getValue%28%29) instead of `toString()`, to get the value. When you call `toString()`, if the class hasn't overriden `toString()` of the inherited `Object.class`, then the `Object#toString()` will be called, which is the memory location of the object.

```
bookInfo(bookName).getBookAvail().get(0).getBookID().getValue();
```

Assuming the value is just a primitive or String, then the output should be fine.

---

```
Student Information is: 
             org.datacontract.schemas._2004._07.lms.ArrayOfStudInfo@2b08bc5a
```

I don't know what the `ArrayOfStudInfo` class is. But it seems to be the same issue, where `Object#toString()` is being called to get the String representation. Without knowing more about the `ArrayOfStudInfo` class, assuming it's *your* class, you could just override `toString()` in that class, to display what you want to be the String representation. For example

```
class ArrayOfStudInfo {
    StudentInfo[] studentInfoArray;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        for (StudentInfo info : studentInfoArray) {
            builder.append(info.getFirstName())
                   .append(" ")
                   .append(info.getLastName())
                   .append("\n");
        }
        return builder.toString();
    }
}
```

Now I have no idea what the class consists of, I'm just throwing an idea out there. If you can't alter the class, then you can always just create a string by extracting the values from the object returned.

---

The point from this is that when you try and put an non-primitive object in a print statement, it needs to have a String representation, which is represented by the `toString()` method.

Comment: thank you so much... the error solved... Thanks a lott